# Matrix operations with normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If A and B are two normal matrices with the same eigenvectors, but different eigenvalues, where, A = UVU' and B = UWU', which operations with A and B (sum, multiplication, inverse, etc,.) will change the eigenvectors of the resultant matrix and which will not?

Comment: What have you tried? $A+B = U(V+W)U'$ and $AB = U(VW)U'$, for example.

Comment: I have tried sum, multiplication and inverse operations together with multiple combinations. One toy example, A^-1 - (A + B'AB)^-1AB', whose eigenvectors are still the same as A and B.